# fortran cudamalloc and cublassetmatrix wrapper problem

Tags: cuda, fortran, malloc

I maybe a problem, either with "cudamalloc" or "cublassetmatrix" not appropriately called from fortran:

```
module cuda
 interface 
   integer (C_INT) function cudaMallocHost(buffer, size)  bind(C,name="cudaMallocHost")
     use iso_c_binding
     implicit none
     type (C_PTR)  :: buffer
     integer (C_SIZE_T), value :: size
   end function cudaMallocHost
   integer (C_INT) function cudaFreeHost(buffer)  bind(C,name="cudaFreeHost")
     use iso_c_binding
     implicit none
     type (C_PTR), value :: buffer
   end function cudaFreeHost
   integer (C_INT) function cudaMalloc(buffer, size)  bind(C,name="cudaMalloc")
     use iso_c_binding
     implicit none
     type (C_PTR)  :: buffer
     integer (C_SIZE_T), value :: size
   end function cudaMalloc
   integer (C_INT) function cudaFree(buffer)  bind(C,name="cudaFree")
     use iso_c_binding
     implicit none
     type (C_PTR), value :: buffer
   end function cudaFree
   integer (C_INT) function cublassetmatrix(M,N,size,A_host,lda_h&
     &,A_dev,lda_d)  bind(C,name="cublasSetMatrix")
     use iso_c_binding
     implicit none
     type (C_PTR) :: A_dev
     type(c_ptr) :: A_host
     integer (C_SIZE_T), value :: size
     integer(C_Int) :: M,N,lda_h,lda_d
   end function cublassetmatrix
   Type(c_ptr) function cudaGetErrorString(err) bind(C,name="cudaGetErrorString")
     use iso_c_binding
     implicit none
     integer (C_SIZE_T), value :: err
   end function cudaGetErrorString
   integer (C_INT) function cublasCreate(handle)  bind(C,name="cublasCreate_v2")
     use iso_c_binding
     implicit none
     Type(C_Ptr) :: handle
   end function cublasCreate
 end interface
end module cuda
program test
  use iso_c_binding
  use cuda
  implicit none
  integer, parameter :: fp_kind = kind(0.0)
  type(C_PTR) :: cptr_A, cptr_A_D
  real (fp_kind), dimension(:,:), pointer :: A=>null()
  real :: time_start,time_end
  integer:: i,j, res, m1
  integer(c_int) :: x
  type(c_ptr) :: handle
  logical:: lsexit
  CHARACTER(len=50), POINTER :: errchar
  m1=500
  res=cublasCreate(handle)
  if(res/=0) Then
    write(*,*) "ERROR 1 ",res;
  end if
  res = cudaMallocHost ( cptr_A, m1*m1*sizeof(fp_kind) )
  if(res/=0) Then
    write(*,*) "ERROR 2 ",res;
  end if
  call c_f_pointer ( cptr_A, A, (/ m1, m1 /) )
  A=1._fp_kind
  res = cudaMalloc ( cptr_A_D, m1*m1*sizeof(fp_kind) )
  if(res/=0) Then
    write(*,*) "ERROR 3 ",res;
  end if
  res=cublasSetMatrix (m1,m1,sizeof(fp_kind),cptr_A,m1,cptr_A_D,m1)
  if(res/=0) Then
    write(*,*) "ERROR 4 ",res,sizeof(fp_kind)
    call c_f_pointer ( cudageterrorstring(int(res,kind=8)),&
      & errchar, [ len(errchar) ] )
    write(*,*) trim(adjustl(errchar))
  end if
end program test
```

The make command is:

```
tmp:
    ifort  -O3 -o tmp $(FFLAGS) tmp.f90 -L/opt/cuda/lib64 -lcublas -lcudart
clean:
    rm tmp cuda.mod
```

Although "cudamallochost" expects "void ** ptr" it seems to work as the fortran pointer is usable, and when put in a loop with "cudafree" does not produce memory leaks.

The code fails at "cublassetmatrix" function either with error code 7 ("too many resources") or 11 ("invalid argument").

Any idea?

Comment: This sounds more like some sort of conflict or error between the version of CUBLAS you have linked against and the CUDA and or driver version you are trying to run on

Comment: If implemented in C/C++, the example runs on the computer with the current version of cuda and gpu drivers.